# ${fileDirname}/*.cpp is not reconized

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

When I directly put in the path like "${fileDirname}/main.cpp", it runs without any problem.

But "${fileDirname}/*.cpp" shows me an error saying `g++: error: PATH: No such file or directory.`

How can I solve this?

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

this is my tasks.json.

Comment: there is no shell expansion, use a build tool: Make, CMake, MSBuild, .....

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5502#issuecomment-629481296

that can resolve your problems.

**WardenGnaw commented on 15 May 2020
Your filepath has a space ( ) in it, so you will need to surround the full command in quotes, but doing so will escape the * and it will not be used as a wildcard.

I cant seem to find a way to escape the spaces in ${fileDirname}, but that will fix the command.**